# Interaction with backend API

Tags: java, spring, api, backend, web-frontend

Goodmorning everyone, I am working on a project that is divided in two parts:

- backend API (based on json)
- Frontend (simple pages in html: form compilation, get information by ID)

I have some problem findind the right structure and technologies to use in the frontend. I am supposed to work with pure javascript? Should I use VueJS/Angular/some other js framework?

The backend is written in Java Spring Boot.

In the future the frontend will have also a feature to book an appointment choosing a timeslot date.

For the frontend I tried with XMLHttpRequest but I had some problem to GET and POST data with the API (code runned but nothing happened)

I tried with this banal code

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "API_URL";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    myFunction(myArr);
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your use cases. I can classify as below. Please refer the link (https://medium.freecodecamp.org/do-we-still-need-javascript-frameworks-42576735949b)

1. Javascript - Less complex
2. Vue.js - Performance concerned
3. React - Performance concerned(vue is better than react in performance)
4. Angular - community support, more matured framework instead of a library go for ANgular 2 and above

Answer (score 1):

You can try with javascript axios library. 
Javascript side example:

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.get('/springEndpoint').then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        // do something with response
    }).catch(() => {
        // do something in case of an error
    })
```

Spring controller example:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/springEndpoint")
    public String someEndpoint() {
        return "test response";
    }
}
```

If you are looking for a way to build spring boot web application with vue.js, this may be useful for you:
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/04/spring-boot-vuejs/

Comment: Thank you Jakube! I think I'll go on with VueJS and Axios. I'll let you know in the next days